# How to implement catalog / registry while obeying immutability and "rules" of functional programming?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, functional-programming, immutability, catalog

Folks,

what is the most appropriate way to implement a registry like

```
trait Registry {
  def registerComponent( name: String, obj : Any ) : Unit
  def getComponent( name: String ) : Any
  def unregisterComponent( name: String ) : Unit
}
```

following functional patterns. ( E.g. immutability, etc. )

What comes to my mind here is

- ***State-Monad***: where the state of the monad represents the registered objects (as `Seq` or similar)
- ***Builder-(like)-Pattern*** but with copying the current registry context from one builder step to the next.

E.g.: A registry following builder-like pattern:

```
case class Registry(registered: Map[String, Any]) {
  def register( name: String, obj: Any ) : Registry = {
    copy( registered = this.registered + ( name -> obj) )
  }
  def unregister( name : String ) : Registry = {
    copy (registered = this.registered.filterKeys( !_.equals(name)))
  }
  // How to deal with return values????
  // Tuple return is quite ugly
  // 
  def getComponent( name: String ) : (Registry, Option[Any]) = {
    (this, registered.get( name ) )
  }
}
```

Which other solutions / patterns are reasonable or available?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: How and where do you consider to use this registry? What will it contain? Who does call those methods, who creates the registry instances? Maybe you just *want* global mutable state here.

Comment: 1. and 2. As context for some larger routines, with the registry holding meta information. 3. and 4. I call the registry and I trigger creation of the registry. Remark: Just want to avoid mutable state.

Comment: You mean a context around those routines, or inside of those routines?

Comment: A context accessible from within these routines.

Comment: And these routines would want to mutate the context, or only access it (`getComponent()`)? It might be beneficial if you could show a short example of what you're doing *with* mutability.

Comment: Most of the context is defined. But context can change. Still, I'm concerned of not having a mutable state at all.

Comment: For that the builder pattern seems fine. You build an immutable context once, and then pass it to each of your routines.

Comment: Maybe. But the builder pattern has problems on returning values ( tuple of builder and value), where I currently see no way to circumvent this. Second, I want to solve the issue most reusable and oriented in a FP way.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the builder pattern? I don't know why `getComponent` would return a `Registry` instance alongside, it should just return the `Component`. It's a getter, it doesn't mutate the registry, does it?

Comment: Bergi, returning the Registry even on `get` is of course not necessary (I was thinking in the direction of the state monad, where you always keep the monad with you). Nevertheless, I have never seen code following the builder pattern that operates on **immutable** datastructures. So I'm excited if this approach is valid, how it compares to state monad and which alternatives exist.

Answer (score 1):

**State Monad** looks like the most appropriate thing if you want to keep your registry in memory. It will look similar to the **Builder** implementation you wrote but will pass context/registry in more functional or less syntactically noisy way.

If you want to push side effects to the boundaries of your program but still have them like saving registry in a database or some mutable structure, then you can use **Reader Monad**.

Here is a [link](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html) to a good article on Scalaz that first discusses the problem of state and then shows how to use State monad.

Comment: Aleksey, you are absolutely right about State and Reader or IO monad. Still, I'm interested in other approaches, patterns or best practices that have proven themself.